# How to separate each white blob from my png images?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am given a png image which is strictly two colours: `Black and White`. More specifically it has a black background and some white marks (we call blobs). Each image has about 30 to 50 such blobs. 
Our task is to generate those 30 to 50 sperate images from our given image, with each having one blob .

For example, we have a given image:

[image: The original image]

We need to convert them into:

[image: Number 1]

[image: Number 2]

[image: Number 3]

And so on with all the blobs. Please guide me on how to do it, I am comfortable with all standard image processing libraries in python.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`scipy.ndimage.measurements.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html):

```
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label

lb = label(my_bw_image)
msks = []
for li in xrange(1, lb.max()+1):
    msks.append(lb==li)
```

You should have all your masks in `msks` list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have trouble converting this into Python 3 code

Comment: There are errors like : AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'max'

Comment: I preferred to use this version for the Python3. 
`labeled_array, num_features = label(image)`
Reference: [Docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html)